# Docker and grunt-based workflow automation

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, vagrant, build-automation, docker

I'm looking for a Docker-based project setup which enables:

1. Development environment to most closely match production
2. Best of breed workflow automation tools for all developers
3. Highly portable/quick to set-up development environment, which supports Linux, OSX, and Windows. Currently we use Vagrant and that seems to be the most obvious choice still.

To satisfy #1:

- Same app container (node.js + Apache) for dev, test, staging and production
- Do *not* add any custom workflow tools to the container just for development's sake

To satisfy #3:

- Do not require developers to all install their own dev tools for their respective environments/OSes (e.g. getting them to install node.js, npm, grunt, etc within the host)

So then to still satisfy #2, the idea I have is:

- have a second "dev" container which shares files with the node/apache container and runs all the workflow automation.
- run all the grunt watch/rebuild/reload/browser-sync etc from within that.
- If using Vagrant, the file sharing would essentially go as host->dev container->app container

Are there any flaws in the above model, or perhaps better ideas?

One potentially missing point is whether to - and if so then how to - avoid performing a full build of containers in production each time. Without risking a mismatch of production vs other containers, I'd like to "package up" the container so that when new code is pushed to production, the app server only needs to restart, instead of npm install, etc. Particularly, once we're pushing to production, it should no longer have to pull anything from third party servers in order to run.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit broad question where answers will be opinionated rather then backed by objective arguments, but here's what I would change there:

1. Node.js is fine, but I would choose nginx instead of Apache. Both Node.js and Nginx are event-based and allow much more throughput, which is one of advantages of Node.js. But this might vary, like if you need certain Apache-only modules, but Nginx seems more natural to put in front of Node.
2. Why do you want to have a separate container? To minimize the production container by it not having to have dev tools?

I really think that having, say, `grunt.js` in the production container not too heavy, but again, you seem to try to minimize impact. Anyway, alternatively you can have both code and `grunt watch` etc inside one container and deploy like that. Pros are that you're simplifying setup, cons are that your production build might install a few extra libs. Which you can mitigate by, for example, setting NODE_ENV to production when deploying production container so that on startup, your scripts will know not to load certain dev tools.

Comment: Good point re: Apache vs nginx. I currently use Apache for a convoluted AWS Elastic Beanstalk issue which wouldn't apply if using Docker. I want to keep all the "dev workflow" tools out of the main container for requirement #1 above. i.e. keep the container as close together in dev and production. If you use env variables to suddenly disable a lot of run-time processes once you switch to production, chances of "but it worked on my box!" problems increase substantially.

Comment: So you want one container for the app itself, and another for build tools to work. The path to code is shared among them and the host OS, so that the dev can work with his own tools and be sure that the result will be the same for others.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I'm just trying to get it so that the "app" container operates as similarly as possible in dev through to production. And yes the source comes from the host OS, so the developer can use their preferred IDE, git, etc.

Comment: BTW, it's nothing to do with saving Megabytes on `grunt.js` or related. It's about having the app server itself behave the same everywhere, i.e. given the same set of source files, you get the same behaviour. Not sure if I'm taking that to too much of an extreme here, but then again containers are meant to be plentiful, right? Hence why not isolate the dev workflow tools from the app itself.

Comment: @rgareth how did that go? I'm pretty much doing the same thing, I have 2 Dockerfiles.tag (1 prod & 1 dev), my build script copies the target dockerfile to the root of the project folder prior to calling the docker build command. for the prod the "compiled" (minimized..) files are baked in, for Dev I use volumes, but having (well documented) issues with the file permissions on the volume within the container, did you have any issues? I'm trying to figure out the best way to have a non-root user run the grunt/npm/bower with sufficient access to generate the files

Comment: maybe ugly, but it's sufficient to sudo chown -R uid:gid the files in the volume, I'm currently not using a dockerdev user within the container which uid:guid are updated to match the external dev uid:guid as some guides show online, but it seems to work fine for my purpose.

Comment: @Vincent I haven't got that far, unfortunately! Does your solution mean you have "different" docker files for prod and dev though? That's what I wanted to avoid. That's why was hoping for a constant "app" container shared everywhere and then a dev support one which is like a sidecar addon for dev environments.

Comment: you want to have your dev/stageing/prod env to run the same, that's right. But once I set up my prod env (nginx serving a static angularjs app which talks through nginx through a uwsgi proxy to a pool of backend servers running django rest framework) you realize that as a dev you need a command line interface to work with (grunt build, django manage database migrations and such). You want to develop in Docker, I got to that point now. Once dev is done, package up and test the build.

Comment: currently most dev laptops on windows, with the docker setup it's a matter of installing boot2docker, running the shell script that pulls the python and node machines and your windows machine has no python/node/grunt/ruby/... needs, all is within containers.

Comment: I want to look at running a local index and squid proxies next as I'm in Vietnam and the seacable broke again, internet is too slow. I also want to look at replacing boot2docker with vagrant. but I went with boot2docker as it's maintained by the same people and handles the docker VM setup for me (for now).